# How to connect Apple AirPort to MiFi hotspot to increase allowed number of devices?

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot, airport, airport-extreme, mifi

I have a wireless MiFi hotspot with a limit of 4 connections. Its DHCP server will only give out 4 IP addresses.

Is it possible to connect an Apple AirPort Extreme to the MiFi's wireless network and then use the AirPort as a DHCP server? This would let me connect more than 4 devices to the MiFi hotspot.

I know the AirPort can act as a bridge and extend another wireless network, but I think it does not act as a DHCP server in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Apple AirPort Extreme does not support the ability to join a wireless network and extend it while simultaneously acting as a NAT gateway and DHCP server.